# How does this struct work

Tags: solidity, ether

Why does this **not** work

```
struct Structure {
    string _var;
}

Structure[] structure;

function addStructure(string _var) {
    Structure _s = Structure(_var);
    ->> structure.push(_s);
}
```

while this works

```
struct Structure {
    string _var;
}

Structure[] structure;

function addStructure(string _var) {
    X
    ->> structure.push(Structure(_var));
}
```

I saw this in an tutorial but it does not work for me.
Thank you for explanation!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the memory keyword:

```
struct Structure {
    string _var;
} 

Structure[] structure;

function addStructure(string _var) {
    Structure memory _s = Structure(_var);
    structure.push(_s);
}
```

The way you wrote it, _s was interpreted as a reference to storage (permanent) memory.  The compiler will not allow an implicit conversion of the temporary memory variable into a storage reference.  The push copies the memory ref in to the permanent structure array.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it and gave me a tip on where to search!